# How do i deploy a java application on windows azure

Tags: java, azure, cloud, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

Hi I am a 3rd year computer science student and I have create a my 3rd year project in java on netbeans and I now want to deploy it onto a virtual machine with windows azure. The point of this is that I would like to be able to use this application as is on any computer connected to the internet simply by accessing the cloud and without having to install the program every time (something like how you can play any game on steam on any pc). The question now is, is it possible and if so how do I do it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a member of [Cloudify](http://www.gigaspaces.com/cloudify-open-paas-stack) development team I would like to recommend the following:

[Cloudify for Azure](http://www.gigaspaces.com/azure) provides just that. It was created to allow you to easily on board any Java application on Azure.

[Cloudify](http://www.gigaspaces.com/cloudify-open-paas-stack) is a free Open Source project maintain as part of the [CloudifySource](http://www.cloudifysource.org) org.

Comment: Does it help to deploy akka http server? Any link to the docs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Today we announced the support for Deploying Java Web Applications on Windows Azure Websites - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/ - check it out.

Comment: I assume that this supports deployment of the standard Java Web Applications that run in Servlet like TomCat, but I am working on Akka Http which is a standalone java Web Server. How do I deploy it on Azure and is there any webapp-like support for it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! With Windows Azure you're not limited to .NET. You can use Java, Python, Node, PHP ... There are a few good tutorials to get started on the official Windows Azure site.

- Cloud Service / PaaS: [Creating a Hello World Application for Windows Azure in Eclipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944)
- Virtual Machines / IaaS: [How to run a Java application server on a virtual machine](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/tutorials/tomcat-on-a-virtual-machine/)

Besides that you might want to take a look at the [Interoperability Bridges](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/Projects.aspx) website.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [Azure Runme](https://github.com/robblackwell/AzureRunMe) project. From what I know, there are commercial projects that use this project to run their Java apps on Azure.