# ASP.Net application or Java SE to Windows Azure Platform

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, swing, azure

I'm interested in developing apps on cloud platform. (Microsoft Azure especially). I've been created with Java SE 8 application by request for my client, and now I'm looking to way to deliver it and my client wants me to maintain it too. I'm quite new to Windows Azure, taking takeover it soon after Christmas, but can I run the Java SE 8 application with Swing GUI -components without anything special skills in Windows Azure?

Or do I have to turn into ASP.Net?

Comment: Azure supports all kinds of stuff. It even has Linux servers available for hosting. That said, if you need a Web application, use Web technologies, such as HTML and Javascript, not some random browser plugin from the 90's full of security holes.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be problem. Azure support multiple platforms.

[How do i deploy a java application on windows azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192709/how-do-i-deploy-a-java-application-on-windows-azure)

Link above talks about how it can be done.

Azure and .net is optimal fit due to availability of tool set. Microsoft is adding rich support build into visual studio, which makes development with Azure very seamless.

Turning the application to .net is bigger questions. It should depends not only on hosting platform but also need of your client. What the tech road map they intend to go. What is current technological landscape looks like and so forth.